# Python: Tkinter with Matplotlib: 1 window on Ubuntu, but 2 in Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter, spyder

I'm writing a program in Python on Ubuntu, which is using Matplotlib and Tkinter to display some graphs.  The issue is that in Ubuntu it runs fine, but in Windows, with Spyder (which the user is going to run it from), it produces the Tkinter window with the plot but also another separate Matplotlib window with the same plot.  I have no idea how to fix this since I do not usually deal with Windows at all.

Here are screenshots that show what is happening:

### Ubuntu:

[image]

---

### Windows:

[image]

---

Here is the code that produces graphs:

```
# This method takes in a lot of data and creates a plot with all the data.  It takes in the x and y data points
# (for the scatter plot), the slope and intercept of the linear best-fit line, the coefficients of the logarithmic
# best-fit curve, the range of the axes to display in the plot, and the titles for the plot and the axes.
# It generates the plot displaying all of this, as well as the equations of the best-fit curves, and their
# R-squared values.  To get the R-squared values, it calls the method which calculates them.

def plotForCorrections(scatterXs, scatterYs, trendlineSlope, trendlineIntercept, logA, logB, axesRange, title, xTitle, yTitle):

    # The linear fit is a straight line, and can be plotted with just two points.
    # The x-coordinates will be the two ends of the plot (the leftmost and rightmost points displayed).
    trendlineXs = numpy.array([axesRange[0], axesRange[1]])

    # We can apply the linear fit equation to the two x-coordinates to get the two y-coordinates.
    trendlineYs = numpy.multiply(trendlineSlope, trendlineXs) + trendlineIntercept

    # We need to clear the plot figure of anything that was on it before.
    plt.clf()

    # Plot the x and y data points
    plt.scatter(scatterXs, scatterYs, color='r')

    # For the x-coordinates for the logarithmic fit curve, we need much more than two, so we
    # create a set of 200 equally spaced points between the two ends of the visible plot.
    # The leftmost point will always be 0, which we can not take the logarithm of.  To remedy that,
    # we use 10^-300 instead of 0.
    logLineXs = numpy.linspace((1e-300 if axesRange[0] == 0 else axesRange[0]), axesRange[1],num=200)

    # We plot the logarithmic fit curve, calculating the y-values of the curve in the same line.
    plt.plot(logLineXs, logFitFun(logLineXs, logA, logB), color='g')

    # We plot the linear fit line.
    plt.plot(trendlineXs, trendlineYs, color='b')

    # We set the axis range of the plot.
    plt.axis(axesRange)

    # We calculate R squared values.
    linRSquared = numpy.round(calculateLinRSquared(scatterXs,scatterYs,trendlineSlope,trendlineIntercept),3)
    logRSquared = numpy.round(calculateLogRSquared(scatterXs,scatterYs,logA,logB),3)

    # We place the equations and R squared values on the plot.
    plt.annotate("Linear trendline (blue):  " + "y = " + str(numpy.round(trendlineSlope,3)) + "x + " +
                 str(numpy.round(trendlineIntercept,3)) + ";  R" + unichr(0x00b2) + " = " + str(linRSquared) + 
                 "\nLogarithmic fit line (green):  " + "y = " + str(numpy.round(logA,3)) + " * ln(x) + " + str(numpy.round(logB,3)) +
                 ";  R" + unichr(0x00b2)+ " = " + str(logRSquared),
                 xy=(0.05,0.90),
                 xycoords="axes fraction")

    # We place the titles on the plot.
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel(xTitle)
    plt.ylabel(yTitle)

    # We display the plot in its window.
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
```

And code for the window:

```
# What follows are GUI-specific things for the plot window
fig = plt.figure()
graphCanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master=window)
questionLabel = Label(window,text="Use this correction?")
linCorrectionButton = Button(window,text="Use Linear Correction",command=clickLinCorrection)
logCorrectionButton = Button(window,text="Use Logarithmic Correction",command=clickLogCorrection)
noCorrectionButton = Button(window,text="Do Not Use a Correction",command=clickNoCorrection)
graphCanvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)
questionLabel.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=3)
linCorrectionButton.grid(row=2,column=0)
logCorrectionButton.grid(row=2,column=1)
noCorrectionButton.grid(row=2,column=2)
cancelButton = Button(window,text="Cancel",command=destroyAndReturn)
cancelButton.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=3)
```

If you need any other code samples please let me know.  Thank you all so much!

Comment: Do you have 2 windows on Windows if you run the script from a console outside of spyder ?

Comment: Well I don't know about running it outside of Spyder, but I'm sure that if I did that it would fix it.  It turned out to be a Spyder issue, and to fix it, all I had to do was make sure I checked "Execute in a new dedicated Python interpreter" in the Run -> Configure (or F6) menu.  Doing that made Spyder easier to work with in all instances too, since before, it would usually give an error about needing an interpreter if I tried to run something, terminate it, and then run it again.

Answer (score 0):

close the plot window before generating new plot.

```
plt.close()
.... etc
```